# How do you give certain people the ability to fly in a Rec Room custom room?

Tags: rec-room

I want to give my moderators the ability to fly so that they can manage the room more effectively, but I don't want everyone to be able to fly. Additionally, I'd like to be able to fly as the owner of the room. How can I set it up my circuits so that only moderators and I can fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, fly is an ability that has to be enabled by a role. Roles can be assigned using the role mapper chip, or in the permission settings. To differentiate between moderators and other players, you will have to use the permissions.

1. Create a role chip and configure it so that it has a speaking name, e.g. "host".
2. Configure it to overwrite and enable flying.
3. Your moderators have to be either hosts or co-owners. If they are just mods and not people who you collaborate with when building the room, make them hosts. For that, open the permissions in your room settings, click the player icon next to the host permission and add them.
4. Click the gear icon for the host permission and find the auto-assign game rules checkbox. Check it and enter the name of your host role from step 1.

The next time your moderators join the room, they should be able to fly. You can also change a bunch of other settings in the role and permission settings, for example you can allow the mods to move faster, always show/hide their names, disable auto-muting etc.